# How can i optimize neo4j query. Neoj4 shows this warning: "This query builds a cartesian product between disconnected patterns"

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to run this query.

```
MATCH (p:Post), (me:User{username: 'someUsername'}) WHERE (
            (
              (me)-[:user_posted_post|user_share_post|post_in_gr|post_in_page]-(p) OR 
              (
                  (me)-[{subscribe: '1'}]-()-[:post_in_gr]-(p)-[:user_posted_post|user_share_post]-({status:'active'}) OR
                  (me)-[{subscribe: '1'}]-()-[:post_in_page]-(p)-[:user_posted_post|user_share_post]-({status:'active'}) OR
                  (me)-[:user_author_page]-()-[:post_in_page]-(p)-[:user_posted_post|user_share_post]-({status:'active'}) OR
                  (me)-[{subscribe: '1'}]-({status:'active'})-[:user_posted_post|user_share_post]-(p:Post{system_type: 'page'}) OR
                  (me)-[{subscribe: '1'}]-({status:'active'})-[:user_posted_post|user_share_post]-(p) AND NOT (p)-[:post_in_gr]-() AND NOT (p)-[:post_in_page]-() OR
                  (me)-[:user_create_com]-()-[:com_in_post]-(p)
              )
              AND p.access IN ['everybody', 'friend'] OR 
              (me)-[:user_can_see_post|user_posted_post]-(p) AND p.access = 'custom'
            ) 
          ) 
          AND p.hidden_id IS NULL AND NOT (me)-[:user_hide_post]-(p) RETURN p ORDER BY p.updated_at DESC
```

Neo4j says: "This query builds a cartesian product between disconnected patterns" and runs the query very slow, about 8 seconds. What is this warning means and how can i avoid it and make it work faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are building a `cartesian product` because of this part : `(p:Post), (me:User{username: 'someUsername'})`

Here you define a pattern that is disjoint : `(p:Post)` & `(me:User{username: 'someUsername'})`. So the DB have to create a cartesain product between those two distinct sets.

But I assume that you have a unique constraint on :User(username), so the cartesian is in reality 1xN, so it'sOK (Neo4j message is just a warning).

Your query is slow due to yours complex where clauses, with a lot of `OR`. Instead of doing this into the where clause, can you try to put it directly in the `MATCH` part or an `OPTIONAL MATCH`.

Moreover, I think that your query can be cut in multiple simple queries, and you can join them with a `UNION`.

Cheers

Comment: thank you. I made it by joining them with a `UNION` and now it works about 5 times faster. But now there is another trouble. Since i use Neo4j 2.3.2, i cannot order the results of all `UNION` queries.